# missing return type in function of object returned by a factory function

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have come across a false error from ESLint, using `@typescript-eslint`, when trying to define the *return type* of a function *inside an object which is returned by a function*.

For example, we have a function returning an object with functions like this:

```
const createStuff = (): StuffReturn => {
    return {
        doStuff: () => { // here ESLint will throw a warning
            return;
        },
    };
};
```

Now when I define the interface `StuffReturn` for the return type of this function as such ...

```
interface StuffReturn {
    doStuff: () => void;
}
```

... and then run ESLint on the command line, I get the following error:

```
13:18 warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
```

maybe I should create an issue on GitHub for this, but I am not sure whether it's actually a bug or I am missing some deeper meaning from this behavior.

Comment: See this comment, it might help https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/149#issuecomment-488555168 There is no change to the `StuffReturn` that will satisfy this rule

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow typed function expressions in your `eslintrc`:

```
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error", {
    "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": true
  }],
}
```

---

This will allow type annotations on the variable of a function expression rather than on the function directly as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md#allowtypedfunctionexpressions).

> Note: If you are using `typescript-eslint` v2 or higher, this option will be `true` by default.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that didn't make a difference. I still get the same error.

I tried to type the `doStuff` function independently of the outer interface and use it in the interface, also I tried to type the whole function `createStuff` including it's return value.

But nothing worked.